# How to give a condition check in the `is()` in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to check if any one of the array element satisfies the given condition. but I get an error that "`is` is not defined".

```
var tempfLength = tempfArray.length;
for(var i=tempfLength-2;i> -1;i--){
   alert(tempfArray[i]);
   if((tempfLength >length)&&(is(tempfArray[i]==parentName))){
     $(this).hide('str');
   }
}
```

Comment: There can be some more easy way to answer it. but need more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
if((tempfLength >length)&&(is(tempfArray[i]==parentName)))
{

}
```

to

```
if( (tempfLength >length) && (tempfArray[i] == parentName) )
{
    // Do something here
}
```

**Note:**

- You can put multiple condition using `&&` or `||`
- You cannot compare 2 objects using `==`

Comment: can you compare 2 objects using the == operator?

Answer (score 0):

the `is()` function is used like:

```
if((tempfLength >length)&&(parentName.is(tempfArray[i])))
{

}
```

Read the documentation:http://api.jquery.com/is/

Make sure that both parentName and tempfArray[i] are jquery objects

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but I think here I can't use this becoz parantName is not a function it is variable. Am I correct?

Comment: @Aash what do you mean by that how do you call a function on another function parantName is a variable you call `is()` on a variable not a function

Comment: Yeah you are right, but when I used this I got errors,"Uncaught TypeError: parentName.is is not a function". and thank you again,  i just searched google for is() and got more info.

Comment: that means parentName or/and  tempfArray[i] are not jquery objects, try wraping them in ` $()` -> `$(parentName).is($( tempfArray[i]))`

Answer (score 0):

> *is is not definded.*

This error says means that the function `is()` isn't available in the ***global*** context you are calling it.

As i understood the issue you can try this with `Array.prototype.find()`:

```
var $this = $(this); // <----make sure to cache it as in the array this doesn't belong to
var tempfLength = tempfArray.length; //`----what you think.
for(var i=tempfLength-2;i> -1;i--){
    alert(tempfArray[i]);
    if((tempfLength >length)&&(tempfArray.find(function(item){item === parentName})))){
      $this.hide('str');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jai for the replay , but it shows it won't work well, again have some kind of error."Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined".

Comment: opps my mistake just forgot to include function find and using array instead.